# Qt - very simple drawing on toggled action

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

This is a very very simple question I think for qt developers.

I have a very large code (I didn't write) that uses qt for drawing, and I just created a `on_actionSomething_toggled(bool checked)` I want it to draw some geometric stuff.

I will just be happy if you could tell me how to get to draw a line (inside that method), I could later draw whatever I want with those lines.

I already tried:

```
void 
MainWindow::on_actionSomething_toggled(bool checked){
  QPainter pa(this);
  pa.drawLine(20, 40, 250, 40);
}
```

But it says:

```
QPainter::begin: Widget painting can only begin as a result of a paintEvent
```

So I just want to know how to draw a simple line inside my `on_actionSomething_toggled` method, or maybe I am doing it everything wrong, and how could I simply add this drawing line functionality inside that big code I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the warning message says, generally the only appropriate time to paint things with a QPainter is from inside the paintEvent() method.

So the usual way to do what you want to do is this:

1) When you want to draw a line, set a member variable to remember that you want to do that (e.g. this->draw_the_line = true;)

2) After setting draw_the_line to its new value, call update() on the widget you want to have a line drawn on ... this will tell Qt to schedule a call to paintEvent() on that widget as soon as possible.

3) Re-implement the widget's paintEvent() method, something like this:

```
void MyWidgetSubclass :: paintEvent(QPaintEvent * e)
{
   TheWidgetSuperclass::paintEvent(e);  // this will draw the widget's usual graphics

   // Plus your custom stuff on top, if appropriate
   if (this->draw_the_line) 
   {
      QPainter p(this);
      p.drawLine(20,40,250,40);
   }
}
```

Note that in order to do this you will have to subclass the widget (so that you can implement your own version of paintEvent() in the subclass, that will be called instead of the usual paintEvent() method) -- if you haven't done so already.

Answer (score 0):

As the warning message says, drawing on widgets can only happen from inside a paint event.

One way to achieve what you want is to paint onto a [QPixmap](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html) first, send an update notification to the widget, and then have the paint event handler draw that pixmap.

Another - perhaps easier and more elegant - way is to prepare the draw operations in a [QPainterPath](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainterpath.html). You then draw that in the widget's paint event handler.

Both ways assume you have implemented your own paint event handler by overriding [QWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#paintEvent).

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [Graphics View Framework](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/graphicsview.html). It manages painting internally. The only thing you need to do in your slot would be:

```
scene->addLine(20, 40, 250, 40);
```